# How to use RBAC to control access to a type of secret resources?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-security

In my k8s cluster, there are some secret resources which are listed below.

> $kubectl get secrets -n istio-system
>   `NAME                                      TYPE`
>   `default-token-4wwkb                       kubernetes.io/service-account-token`
>   `istio-ca-secret                           istio.io/ca-root`
>   `istio-ca-service-account-token-rl4xm      kubernetes.io/service-account-token`
>   `istio-egress-service-account-token-vbfwf  kubernetes.io/service-account-token`
>   `istio-ingress-certs                       kubernetes.io/tls`
>   `istio-ingress-service-account-token-kwr85 kubernetes.io/service-account-token`
>   `istio-mixer-service-account-token-29qbb   kubernetes.io/service-account-token`
>   `istio-pilot-service-account-token-t6kmf   kubernetes.io/service-account-token`
>   `istio.default                             istio.io/key-and-cert`
>   `istio.istio-ca-service-account            istio.io/key-and-cert`
>   `istio.istio-egress-service-account        istio.io/key-and-cert`
>   `istio.istio-ingress-service-account       istio.io/key-and-cert`
>   `istio.istio-mixer-service-account         istio.io/key-and-cert`
>   `istio.istio-pilot-service-account         istio.io/key-and-cert`
>   `istio.test-istio-sa                       istio.io/key-and-cert`
>   `test-istio-sa-token-4zm9k                 kubernetes.io/service-account-token`

Now I want to use rbac to control a service account test-istio-sa, so that test-istio-sa can only access to all secrets of type kubernetes.io/service-account-token, such as istio-ca-service-account-token-rl4xm, and istio-ingress-service-account-token-kwr85.

I create a Role kube-sa-token-reader, and bind it to service account test-istio-sa.

```html
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: kube-sa-token-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["secrets/kubernetes.io/service-account-token"] # grant access to all service account tokens
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

```html
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-kube-sa-token
  namespace: istio-system
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-istio-sa
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: kube-sa-token-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

But it seem does not work as expected.
`$ kubectl auth can-i get secret/kubernetes.io/service-account-token -n istio-system --as system:serviceaccount:istio-system:test-istio-sa`

`no - Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:istio-system:test-istio-sa"`

Comment: flagged for move to serverfault

Comment: What is serverfault?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ the stackexchange site for sysadmin/devops questions.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the information!

Comment: Does the service account `system:serviceaccount:istio-system:test-istio-sa` actually exist? Do you see it listed when you execute `kubectl get sa -n=istio-system`?

Comment: Yes, the service account already exists. I can find it by $ kubectl get serviceaccounts -n istio-system

Comment: Curses that someone sent you off SO to serverfault. @JimmyCYJ did you ever end up getting this working?